# Oracle APEX - success message being displayed if no changes were made on the form

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

On my page a I have a PL/SQL process that updates the database. If the process is successful, I want to display a success message. The way I am doing this now is by setting a Success Message property of my process to a page item that contains success message - `&P1_SUCCESS_MSG.`
I also set `Error` property of my process to `&P1_ERROR_MSG.`.

Both P1_SUCCESS_MSG and P1_ERROR_MSG gets set inside the process. Now the issue I have is when the user clicks the `Save` button, thus activating the process, without changing anything one the form. The success message is displayed regardless if any changes were made. I was wondering if there is an easy way to check if the form was changed and prevent the success message from being displayed if not changes were made to the database

Answer (score 0):

If success message is displayed, it means that `:P1_SUCCESS_MSG` has value. Why? It should be empty by default and set only if procedure completes successfully and changes *something*.

For that purpose, I'd create a stored procedure with one (or two) `OUT` parameter(s); the same parameter might be used to inform user of what happened. That `OUT` parameter would be used to set `:P1_SUCCESS_MSG` item's value.

So, if something has been done, it would say e.g.

> Procedure successfully completed.

Otherwise,

> Nothing has been done.